# $GLOBALS variable weird behavior

Tags: php, superglobals

I am trying to understand superglobals in PHP. This is my script:

```php
<?php

$n = $GLOBALS['abc'] + 1;
$GLOBALS['abc'] = $n;
echo $GLOBALS['abc'];

?>
```

When I access this file from browser, only 1 gets printed every time. Why isn't the value getting incremented each time I reload the page? Why is the value of $GLOBALS['abc'] getting lost?

Comment: 1. Don't use `$GLOBALS` 2. PHP is [stateless](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/101337/whats-the-difference-between-stateful-and-stateless). That's a *very* important thing to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the value in a file / database / cache for persistence. Store and read on next request. PHP is stateless means every request is independent in itself.